# Windows UIAutomation get file type

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

Is it possible to get the file type using the UI Automation ?

In a folder if i have multiple files with same name but different extensions, and I have to select a file using the screen co-ordinates. We get the IUIAutomationElement, and can get only the file names and in case user has not selected the settings  "Show file extensions" in the windows, then i am not able to distinguish between the files.

Was also thinking if i could trace it through the help text/tool tip. But not sure how to get the handle for tooltip in UI Automation.

I saw similar old thread, but no answer to it.. 
[UI Automation / Retrieve File Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629174/ui-automation-retrieve-file-extension)

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to do that:

---

a. change the `Show File Extensions` through the UI by using the UIA Framework

- *-Not Recommended-*

---

b. retrieve the `Folder Path` through the UIA or any other way and then through the `File` Class, call the Method `File.GetFiles` and then `Path.GetExtension` to get the extension of each file.

- -Recommended

Answer (score 1):

No.  UI Automation shows what's currently available on screen.  You should be using `IShellFolder` or other shell APIs.